# Is there some algorithms to generate similar tweets?

Tags: text, artificial-intelligence

I have study task. I have some tweet. Is there some common algorithms to generate similar tweets?

Comment: So what have you studied so far?

Comment: @reto, I have not studied any objects in the area. This is research project.

Comment: [Markov Chains](http://agiliq.com/blog/2009/06/generating-pseudo-random-text-with-markov-chains-u/) are interesting yet simple models to implement. If you don't mind to generate text that potentially does not make sense, you can get it done in a matter of tens of minutes.